# jQuery Sort appends div on Drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following:

```
$(".myclass").sortable();

$("#mydiv").droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).append( "<div>Test</div>" );
    }    
});
```

After I drop on #mydiv it appends the div as expected,but when I use the sortable and drop again it appends another div. What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you got a draggable element? Can you provide it?

Comment: Yes I have a draggable and its working. The problem is every time I sort and drop its firing the droppable and appending on each sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the dropped element is coming from a draggable or a sortable. To do so you can check if the element have the `ui-draggable` class, if not exit you function.

Code:

```
$("#mydiv").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if (!ui.draggable.hasClass('ui-draggable')) return
        $(this).append("<div>Test</div>");
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/hsTFN/